# Contract NOT created when using "new" on testnet

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan, web3j

I've got a contract which one of his functions creates a new contract in the following manner: (Solidity)

```
function createCarrier()
public
{
    P2Carrier newCarrier = new P2Carrier(msg.sender);
    emit contractCreated(address(newCarrier));
}
```

I've deployed this to Rinkeby TestNet.
When making a transaction to call this function (from android using web3j, and infura as http provider) The event is emitted, but when I look for the address emitted in the event, There is nothing there (using rinkeby.etherscan.io). 
also, I can see the transaction sent to call the function in etherscan, but I cant see any additional contract creation transaction.

you can see the contract info and transaction here:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7ca846b6d52ccec650187e5ed8e793701de4d00e

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The contract is being created. The geth debug trace shows the CREATE opcode and storing of the code.

Additionally, if you call `getCode` on geth for one of the deployed addresses (from [this](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe7778dc26f020fe1596d5a48353d66895f7e1b07e59442fb2d5f81c514023ecb#eventlog) tx's log), you get some code back. [Here's](https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getCode&address=0x98a9e86209a6847d173b2063e76179fd6d26dcd0&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) the Etherscan API call for that

It looks like Etherscan is just not indexing the contract correctly when deployed from another contract on Rinkeby, I'm not sure why. I know it does it for ropsten and the mainnet. Try using ropsten if you really must see it on etherscan.